# How can i get the video capture options in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am developing one appliation.In that i am doing video in iphone using UIIMagePickercontroller.So my problem is how can i get the video capture options(quality,flash etc) symbols on screen programatically.So please tell me how can i do this one.

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Comment: Just i declare the picker and set the mode as video and open the picker.I didn't know how can i get that options.

Comment: Have you set the media types for the imagePicker ?

Comment: Just post your code for the imagePicker alone. So that I can know what the problem is ?